# JQuery Login Redirect. Code Included

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

Hey What am I doing wrong here? Extremely new to ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#empty').show(500);
    $('#reg').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'logina.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            type : $('#typeof').val(),
            login : $('#login').val(),
            pass : $('#pass').val(),


        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#empty').show(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500)
            if(data.error === false) 
                window.location.replace("http://blahblah.com/usercp.php");      
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#reg').show(500);
                $('#empty').hide()
        },

        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text("There was an Error. Please try again.").show(500);
            $('#reg').show(500);
            $('#empty').hide();
                                Recaptcha.reload();

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

It logs in just fine and gives the success message just fine just no luck on the window.location.replace. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `data.error` is true, even though you ended up in the `success` branch. Try putting alerts to clarify your program flow.

`success : function(data){
            alert('success branch');
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#empty').show(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500)
            if(data.error === false) 
                alert('no data error');
                window.location.replace("http://blahblah.com/usercp.php");

            if (data.error === true)
                alert('data error');
                $('#reg').show(500);
                $('#empty').hide()
        },`

Comment: Tested... didnt work. Gave the success message but no redirect. Thanks any how!

Comment: You might try just plain old `window.location.href = "http://blahblah.com/usercp.php";`. I don't see why it would be different, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
if(data.error === 'false') 
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
...
```

or

```
...
if(data.error == 'false') 
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
...
```

Comment: Tested both still no luck. Thanks though!

Comment: from php return $data['error']='false'; not $data['error']=false;

Comment: Hey do if and else statements have brackets in JQuery like they do in php?

Comment: becouse from php you return string with value 'false' and in js we check if returned data is string with value 'false'. you could return anything else, for example 1 for succes and 0 for error...

Answer (score 0):

you missed some semicolon (will break in IE):

```
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500); //<- HERE
(...)
$('#empty').hide(); // <- HERE
```

**edit:** now you use a lot of show/hide events, you want to show a message, and then do the redirect. You should chain your redirect at the end of the show event (so the show animation wait until the end before doing the redirect:

```
$('#message').removeClass()
    .addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
    .text(data.msg).show(500, function(){
        if(data.error === false) 
                window.location.replace("http://blahblah.com/usercp.php");      
        (...)
    });
```

But anyway, other responses certainly contains the main cause of your bug. i.e debug what you have in data.error, it's maybe not false.

Comment: added another issue, but still not the good one I think :-) Oh and if data.error can only be true or false an if/else would be better than 2 if.

Comment: Hey are there brackets in JQUERY if/else? I tried if(data.error !== true) and I still have no luck...