# Redirection Still not working (updated on earlier question)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So earlier I asked this question: [JQuery Login Redirect. Code Included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650689/jquery-login-redirect-code-included/4650769#4650769)

The php file is sending the following:

```
$return['error'] = false;
$return['msg'] = 'You have successfully logged in!!';
```

I've tried all the suggestions, quoting the error on php and ajax end, 2 equals instead of 3, I've also tried DNE true which should be the same as an else statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {
$('#waiting').show(500);
$('#empty').show(500);
$('#reg').hide(0);
$('#message').hide(0);

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'logina.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        type : $('#typeof').val(),
        login : $('#login').val(),
        pass : $('#pass').val(),


    },
    success : function(data){
        $('#waiting').hide(500);
        $('#empty').show(500);
        $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
            .text(data.msg).show(500)
        if(data.error != true) 
            window.location.replace("http://blahblah.com/usercp.php");      
        if (data.error === true)
            $('#reg').show(500);
            $('#empty').hide()
    },

    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#waiting').hide(500);
        $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
            .text("There was an Error. Please try again.").show(500);
        $('#reg').show(500);
        $('#empty').hide();
                            Recaptcha.reload();

    }
});

return false;
```

});

And it still wont work. Any ideas on how to make a redirection work if login is successful and error returns false? Also while I am asking, can I put a `.delay(3000)` 3s at the end of `window.location.replace("http://blahblah.com/usercp.php")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of considering all options, you do call `echo json_encode($return);` in your php script right?

Also, for the delay, I would say put the code in a `setTimeout()` call to be run in 3000ms.

Comment: Yeah I do. I get the error messages just fine. The true and false ones (they appear as green and red divs) its just cant get a redirection working when error returns false.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `window.location = "http://blahblah.com/usercp.php";`? Also, just a note, based on your indentation it looks like you think that `$('#empty').hide()` in your `success` function is going to run only `if (data.error === true)` which is not the case. I know people argue with me about this but I think that you should always specify the block that you are referencing (aka put curly brackets around it). It just makes it explicit and clear. /endrant

Comment: Hey, tried what you suggested... still no luck. Maybe this will help you help me: The redirection doesnt even work if its not in an if statement either.

Comment: @NoviceCoding: Are you sure that the success function is firing at all? Try adding an `alert();` to the success callback.

Comment: Hey Drackir thanks for all the help. You got me looking into the relocation function and I got it to work using:      $(window.location).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');

Comment: However, settimeout() makes it not work and .delay doesnt do squat. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Try this code: `setTimeout("$(window.location).attr('href', 'google.com';);", 3000);` This should work. Note that Timeout is capitalized. I've fixed this in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code specifies the dataType is JSON so your PHP should return:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "msg": "You have successfully logged in!!"
}
```

Comment: Nope you can return a JSON object like this or an array.

Comment: But how does this help my redirection issues? Also can you tell me how to return that? I am currently using echo json_encode($return);

Comment: I'm not much of a PHP expert, but I suspect that you code will do that. I assumed from your question you were not returning real JSON.